# Parameter uncertainly estimation in nonlinear optimization

Tags: nonlinear-regression, uncertainty

I appreciate if somebody introduces me some books on parameter uncertainty estimation or parameter confidence interval estimation in nonlinear optimization.

For the linear regression I understand that there is some closed form formula, however, for the nonlinear minimization problem I am at lost and have no clue where to look. I hear methods such as Hamiltonian Monte Carlo, however, is this the only method?

Comment: Do you have a specific function you're trying to fit data to?  The approach will depend on that function (since, if it can be linearized, it would be advantageous to do so )

Comment: The model itself is a collection of nonlinear complicated functions which at the end generate a two dimensional output. This two dimensional output is subtracted from the two dimensional experimental data (an image) and then each element is squared and summed to provide an objective function which is then minimized to get the unknown parameters.

Comment: Can you provide more information?  This sounds nearly like a deep learning model form what you're telling me